# Is it possible to accept a post w/ no content length in GAE?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, go

I am moving a small service, written in GO, to Google App Engine. That service receives some posts from a few buggy embedded devices that have a valid post body but don't submit a Content Length header. There is no body and Apache didn't care about this but Google App Engine returns a 411 error (as it should). I didn't catch this in development because the local server is totally fine w/o the content length header.

I'm wondering, is there a way to catch that error in my application or is that beyond my control?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Is the post request reaching your app (do you see it in the logs)? Or the infra catches it before?

Comment: I do not believe it is making it to the app. I don't see it in the logs. Which is why I'm assuming this is an App Engine thing. Especially since running their server local this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [RCF 7230 - 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) only responses could contain a body without a `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Without such information, for a request, then message can:

- be treated as a message with body size zero
- or be rejected with 411 error.

So, yes, as you said, the clients are clearly wrong on the protocol side. And you cannot do anything about that, the message is rejected before reaching your application, even if you had one way of allowing these bad message in GAE servers, any other proxy or load balancer set between these bad clients and GAE servers could also reject the messages.